In Kotlin/Android, can I use withContext() and withTransaction together?
The situation is that I have to combine networkcalls and database executions in a single method, as in this pseudocode:
do {
   fetchPagedDataFromNetwork
   insertDataIntoDatabase
} while not last page

Of course this should run in a transaction, and should (as I understood it) use Dispatchers.IO execution context.
Please note that this will run in a suspendable Coroutine, so neither @Transactional nor runInTransaction()can be used, from my understanding of the issue.
Could this be done, and what sequence would be preferrable?
Pseudocode (A), transactional block within context
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try {
         database.withTransaction {
            // get data from network and and insert paged data into database
         }
      }
      finally {...}
   }
}

or would this be better?
Pseudocode (B), context within transactional block
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
   try {
      database.withTransaction {
         withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // get data from network and and insert paged data into database
         }
      }
   }
   finally {...}
}

Thanks for enlightement, from an Android/Kotlin newbie ;-)
